# Finding a plane parallel to one given line and contains other given line

Tags: vectors, systems-of-equations, solid-geometry

For some reason I can't figure out how to Find a plane which contains L1:\begin{cases} 3x+3y+5z=8 & (1) \\ 5x+5y -3z=2 & (2)\end{cases}

and parallel to the direction of L2: (34,34,4)

I know that the cross product of L1 gives me the plane vector -34i + 34j +0k, but i'm getting stuck there.
Would really appreciate some help.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Added, Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\vec{l_1}(a,b,c)$ be a direction of $l_1$.

Thus, $$3a+3b+5c=0$$ and $$5a+5b-3c=0,$$ which gives $$\vec{l_1}(1,-1,0).$$
Now, let $\vec{n}(a,b,c)$ be a normal of the plane.

Thus, $$17a+17b+2c=0$$ and $$a-b=0,$$ which gives $$\vec{n}(1,1,-17)$$
and since a point $(1,0,1)$ is placed on the plane, we obtain the following equation:
$$1(x-1)+1(y-0)-17(z-1)=0$$ or
$$x+y-17z+16=0.$$

$(1,0,1)$ is placed on the plane because
$$3\cdot1+3\cdot0+5\cdot1=8$$ and
$$5\cdot1+5\cdot0-3\cdot1=2.$$

Comment: thanks you so much!, but how did you know to place the point (1,0,1) on the plane?

Comment: I added something, Rom. See now.

Comment: Amazing, thanks!

Comment: בבקשה והיזהר מקורונה

Comment: תודה מיכאל!! גם אתה :)

Answer (score 0):

Let $$P_1: 3x+3y+5z=8,~~P_2: 5x+5y-3z=2$$
Eq. of family of plane through the intersection of $P_1$ and $P_2$  is
$$P_3: P_1+tP_2=0 \implies (3+5t)x+(3+5t)y+(5-3t)z-(8-2t)=0~~~~(1)$$ since $P_3$ contains a line with  drs $\vec L\{34,34,4\}$ it is perpendicular to the normar to the plane 
$\vec N=\{3+5t, 3+5t,5-3t\}$ So
$$\vec N . \vec L=0 \implies 68(3+5t)+4(5-3t)=0 \implies t=-\frac{28}{41} $$
Putting this value of $t$ in (1) we get the required plane.

Comment: thank you very much!

Comment: You repeat a common error here: The family $P_3$ doesn’t contain $P_2$ itself. Fortunately, $P_2$ isn’t the solution so you can get away with that parameterization.

Comment: @amd $P_3$ with $t=-28/41$ is the required plane. which contains the common line of intersection of $P_1$ and $P_2$........

Comment: You’ve missed the point. The solution you eventually arrive at is correct; your error lies in the assertion that the family of planes through the intersection of $P_1$ and $P_2$ Is $P_1+tP_2$. It is not, since it doesn’t include $P_2$.

Comment: @amd Sorry! I beg to differ. It   is well known that $P_1+t P_2$ are family of planes passing through the line of intersection of $P_1$ and $P_2$.

Comment: In that case, tell me what value of $t$ produces the plane $P_2$, which obviously contains the intersection of $P_1$ and $P_2$, so is also a member of the family. If by “well known” you mean “widely repeated mistake,” I’m in agreement with you.